# Divergence of the stress-energy tensor

Tags: general-relativity, conservation-laws, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I am currently going through *The large scale of space-time* by Hawking and Ellis and I am having trouble understanding their proof that the divergence of the stress-energy tensor is 0. The part of the book in question in chapter 4 ("General relativity"), section 3.3 ("Lagrangian formulation").

To put things in context, they work in Lagrangian formalism and define the stress-energy tensor as the derivative (up to a factor 2) of the action with respect to the metric -which is quite usual I think.

Now, they claim:

$$\frac{1}{4!}\int_{\mathcal{D}}\!\mathcal{L}_X(L\eta) = \sum_i\int_\mathcal{D}\!\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial{\psi_{(i)}}^{a\ldots b}_{c\ldots d}} - \left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial{\psi_{(i)}}^{a\ldots b}_{c\ldots d\ ;\ e}} \right)_{;\ e}\right)\mathcal{L}_{X}{\psi_{(i)}}^{a\ldots b}_{c\ldots d}\,\mathrm{d}v + \frac{1}{2}\int_{\mathcal{D}}\!T^{ab}\mathcal{L}_{X}g_{ab}\,\mathrm{d}v$$

$L$ is the lagrangian density, $\mathcal{L}$ denotes the Lie derivative and $\eta$ is the $4$-form $4!\sqrt{|\det(g_{\alpha\beta})|} \mathrm{d}x^1 \wedge \mathrm{d}x^2 \wedge \mathrm{d}x^3 \wedge \mathrm{d}x^4$.

Obviously then, you can cancel the first series of integrals because of the Euler-Lagrange equations and by rewriting the last integral, you deduce $T^{ab}_{\ ;\ a} = 0$. The problem is I don't see how they obtain the equality written above.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that Leibniz's rule $\mathcal{L}_X(L\eta)=(\mathcal{L}_XL)\eta +L(\mathcal{L}_X\eta)$ holds for the Lie derivative. The Lie derivative of the lagrangian is
\begin{equation}
  \mathcal{L}_XL=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \psi}
  \mathcal{L}_X\psi+\frac{\partial L}{\partial
  (\partial_e\psi)}\mathcal{L}_X(\partial_e\psi)+
  \frac{\partial L}{\partial g_{ab}}\mathcal{L}_Xg_{ab},
\end{equation}
omitting the indices of the fields and the summation over them, for simplicity of notation. We will also need the Lie derivative of the volume form $\mathcal{L}_X\eta=(\partial\eta/\partial g_{ab})\mathcal{L}_Xg_{ab}$.

Using $\mathcal{L}_X(\partial_e\psi)=\partial_e(\mathcal{L}_X\psi)$ and integration by parts in the second term we get:
\begin{equation}
  \int_\mathcal{D}\mathcal{L}_X(L\eta)=
  \int_\mathcal{D}\eta\left[\frac{\partial L}{\partial \psi}
  \mathcal{L}_X\psi-\partial_e\left(
  \frac{\partial L}{\partial(\partial_e\psi)}\right)
   \mathcal{L}_X(\psi)+
  \frac{\partial L}{\partial g_{ab}}\mathcal{L}_Xg_{ab}\right]+
  \int_\mathcal{D}L\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial g_{ab}}\mathcal{L}_Xg_{ab}.
\end{equation}

Finally, the integrands in the third and fourth terms can be written together as
\begin{equation}
  \left(
    \frac{\partial L}{\partial g_{ab}}\eta +
    L\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial g_{ab}}
  \right)\mathcal{L}_Xg_{ab}=
  \frac{\partial}{\partial g_{ab}}(L\eta)\mathcal{L}_Xg_{ab}=
  \frac{\delta S}{\delta g_{ab}}\mathcal{L}_Xg_{ab}=
  \frac{1}{2}T^{ab}\mathcal{L}_Xg_{ab},
\end{equation}
as desired.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I am still having trouble understanding why we can commute the Lie derivative $\mathcal{L}_X$ with $\partial_e$. Also, I am not sure what kind of derivative you are thinking of when writing $\partial_e\psi$ where $\psi$ is a tensor. A covariant derivative, a Lie derivative, or something else?